# ASP.NET Core missing line numbers in exception

Tags: asp.net-core

I created new project: ASP.NET Core Web Application (**.NET Core**) and test throw new exception in controller and catch the exception. In exception is no line numbers (exception.ToString()). I added System.Diagnostics.StackTrace to project.json, but line numbers are still missing, even with debugger.

When I change Core framework project to full .NET framework, line numbers are OK. Can I get line numbers of exception in Core framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me, enabling **Portable PDB** or setting **Optimize** didn't fix the problem.

But I tried changing the **Debugging information** to "Full" in Advanced Build Settings and it worked.

Follow the below procedure:

1. Open the "Properties" of your startup project.
2. Goto "Build".
3. Click on "Advanced" under Output section.
4. Change the **Debugging information** to "Full".

[image]

Comment: I was able to get line numbers with PDB-Only as Jeow Li Huan mentions.

Answer (score 2):

When I enable **portable PDBs** in Core framework -> line numbers are back :-)

Enable portable PDBs in project.json:

```
"buildOptions": {
"debugType": "portable",
...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: in release build, instead of proper line numbers I was getting `line 0` in stack traces; fixed by disabling optimizations; in project.json:

```
"configurations": {
    "Release": {
        "buildOptions": {
            "optimize": false
        }
    }
}
```